# How do I write a scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I am trying to learn how to write scopes in Rails.

I have models for user, organisation and organisation request.  The associations are:

```
User
  has_one :organisation 

Organisation
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :organisation_requests

Organisation_request
  belongs_to :organisation
```

In my organisation request model, I'm trying to write a scope to pick out all the organisation requests that belong to the organisation's owner.

```
scope :same_org, where(:organisation_id => owner.organisation_id)
```

Then in my organisation_requests controller, I have:

```
def index
    @organisation_requests = OrganisationRequest.same_org
end
```

I tried the above. Owner is an alias for user. In each organisation, one user is nominated as that organisation's owner. I want that user to see an index of the organisation requests that come in for that owner's organisation.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here? I'm not understanding something about how to write scopes.

Comment: The syntax uses a lambda, as Hasmukh's answer shows. See [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

Comment: hey, did you get this one solved?

Comment: Hi @AndreyDeineko - I'm still trying to solve it.I've got another issue that is stopping me from calling the scope - so I'm working on that first. I have your notes and will update to accept your answer if I get it working. Thanks for following up. I'm very slow to learn...

Comment: hey good luck! We have all been starting some time ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your model, try this:

```
scope :same_org, -> {where(:organisation_id => owner.organisation_id) }
```

Comment: Wrong. how do you expect owner to have `organisation_id` in a relation, where `organisation` `belongs_to` owner?

Answer (score 1):

The upvoted answer is wrong (nothing personal, **@Hasmukh Rathod**) - there is no `organisation_id` column in `users` table (it's actually vice versa - there is a `user_id` column in `organisations` table).

I would suggest the following solution:

```
scope :same_org, ->(owner_id) { joins(organisation: :user).where(users: { id: owner_id }) }
```

Having the above scope, what you'll need to do, is to pass the `owner_id` as an argument. I'm sure there is a way to get it working without passing an argument to scope, but I'm not yet sure how (I've just woke up :D).

So example:

```
owner_id = User.find(1).id
OrganisationRequest.same_org(owner_id) # would give you the expected collection of requests
```